# What happens with a thread if it's in a infinite while loop python

Tags: python, multithreading, blockingqueue

I found this article about queue's in python: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/01/python-concurrency-an-example-of-a-queue/

It works fine but I have question about it. In the run method of the thread we see:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        # gets the url from the queue
        url = self.queue.get()

        # download the file
        self.download_file(url)

        # send a signal to the queue that the job is done
        self.queue.task_done()
```

The thread is in a infinite while-loop without calling break. What happens to this thread when the program ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "the program ends". If the main thread just reaches the end of its execution, there are two possibilities:

1. If the thread is a non-daemon `threading.Thread`, the running thread will keep the program alive indefinitely.
2. If the thread is a daemon, the thread will be abruptly terminated as soon as the main thread ends.

The [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) property is described in the docs like this:

> A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread
>   (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called,
>   otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from
>   the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and
>   therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon =
>   False.
>
> **The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.**

If by "program ends" you mean the process gets a SIGTERM or SIGKILL or something similar, then the thread will terminate along with the rest of the program, even if its not a `daemon`.

Comment: @Veedrac In this case

Comment: @VincentBeltman It depends. If you need your background threads to exit gracefully for any reason, then you don't want them to be daemons. Instead, you'd want to send a signal to them that they should shut down at the point the main thread ends. A good way to do that for your use-case is to send `None` into the `Queue` that the thread consumes from when you're ready to shut down, and have the thread exit when it receives one.

Comment: @VincentBeltman So, it's not acceptable for `download_file` to be terminated in the middle of downloading the file, you don't want the thread to be a daemon.

Comment: So i should use queue.join() ;)